# Batch set variable

Tags: variables, batch

En batch, necesito establecer en una variable la línea que leo desde un fichero ie: properties.yml

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in (properties.yml) do (
    echo %%a| find /I "automatic">Nul && (set automatic="%%b")
    echo %%a| find /I "interval">Nul && (set interval="%%b")
)
```

siendo properties.yml:

```
scheduler:
  automatic: on
  interval: /sc weekly /d SUN /st 00:00
```

El problema que tengo es que la variable %interval% no contiene toda la línea después de ":" y tan solo establece el valor "/sc"

```
echo %interval%
/sc
```

¿Alguna sugerencia sobre cómo obtener la línea entera después de los ":" en una variable?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías probar diciéndole que el segundo token es toooodo lo que va después del delimitador, cambiando `2` por `*`:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%a in (properties.yml) do (
    echo %%a| find /I "automatic">Nul && (set automatic="%%b")
    echo %%a| find /I "interval">Nul && (set interval="%%b")
)
```